# DWORD values in Output pane of Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

Is there anyway to force Visual Studio to report DWORD values by their text name rather than in numerical format? For instance, the DirectInput DIDEVCAPS structure uses the dwFlags member. When an instance is shown in Output, I only receive an numerical value, rather than the text values described on msdn site (DIDC_ALIAS, DIDC_ATTACHED, DIDC_DEADBAND, etc). I have tried looking in the definition file, and it lists the text name (macro name, DWORD name?), and it provides these members with the hex values, which convert to the correct numerical values, but converting from int to hex, then looking in the definition file, is a bit more work than I would like to do? I also checked the net for a list of DWORD values and their corresponding numerical values, but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: You could write a function that checks each flag and outputs the name that you could call in the debugger. `OutputDebugString` would route it to the output window.

Comment: `DWORD` is just another way of saying `unsigned long`. There is no such thing as a _"list of DWORD values"_ because a `DWORD` is just an integer with possible values from 0 to 4294967295. It is not an enumeration. Similarly, `DIDC_ATTACHED` is just a constant defined as having the value 1. It is not an enumerator. There may be arbitrary amount of other constants also defined as having the value 1. For example, `FILE_SHARE_READ` used in `CreateFile()` function (when specifying the `DWORD dwShareMode` parameter) has also the value 1.

Comment: The debugger does not know that the values were initially named constants (not even the compiler does, for that matter). There's not much the debugger can do. It's just values at that point. If you want to improve the debugging experience, you can use [format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp) in the debugger. Using hexadecimal display is usually sufficient to see individual flags.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above recommendations:

There is no way to force Visual Studio to report DWORD values by their text name rather than in numerical format.

The debugger does not know that the values were initially named constants. You could try to write a function that checks each flag and outputs the name that you could call in the debugger.